# Android : PayPal integration

Tags: android, paypal

I have to implement `PayPal` in my android application. I have tried with the code but I am getting this error:

`RelativeLayout01` **cannot be resolved or is not a field**

My paypal code is as follows:

```
private void showPayPalButton() {

    // Generate the PayPal checkout button and save it for later use
    PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
    View launchPayPalButton = pp.getCheckoutButton(this, PayPal.BUTTON_278x43, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);

    // The OnClick listener for the checkout button
    launchPayPalButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

    // Add the listener to the layout
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    params.bottomMargin = 10;
    launchPayPalButton.setLayoutParams(params);
    int PAYPAL_BUTTON_ID = 0;
    launchPayPalButton.setId(PAYPAL_BUTTON_ID);
    ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout01)).addView(launchPayPalButton);
    ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout01)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    }
```

I have added the .jar file in my project. Kindly help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Is this id exist `RelativeLayout01`? show your layout xml